# #VALUE error when trying to multiply a field range

Tags: excel

Very simple problem in MS Excel (that is what I think). Following formula:
=SUM((D9:D26)*1)

Gives me a #VALUE! error.

Why? Cannot I not multiply the sum of a bunch of fields?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, the formula you are looking for is `=SUM(D9:D26)*1`

The idea is to multiply the sum which is computed with this formula `SUM(D9:D26)` and a multiplier of your choice by adding `* 1` *outside* the first formula. An extra set of parentheses prevents Excel from *parsing* the formula correctly.

Comment: No you are not missing something, I'm! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply outside the `SUM(...)` call, not inside.

Remove the outer parentheses.